# What is the secure way to send javascript code as a POST Request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, yui, xss

I am currently building a UI for my map reduce program . In the UI , the user is asked for the following 
1. Cluster Name ( where the MR operation is to be run )
2. Mapper Function
3. Reducer Function

Currently i do as POST request using  YUI io module.

```
     sUrl = "http://hostname.com/start";
     var cfg = {
                 method: "POST",
                 data:  "host_expr="+host_expr+"&mapper="+mapper+"& reducer="+reducer,
                 headers: { 'X-Transaction': 'POST Example', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
                };
     var request = Y.io(sUrl, cfg);
```

But i guess , this method is vulnerable since , i am sending the whole code as a post request . So i am wondering if there is any other method to securing do a POST request.

The mapper and reducer code are written in javascript ( this cannot be changed) . Needless to say , server side is javascript too (nodejs).

PS : by securing i mean ,
!.  The above code afaik looks vulnerable to xss Besides i dont know whether its a good idea to send javascript code as a POST request.

1. i am also trying to prevent misuse of javascript execution . The MR functions written in javascript can be maligned.

Comment: "Secure" is a vague term. **Who** are you trying to prevent doing **what**?

Comment: Fyi, you can pass an object for the `data` argument instead of a string. When passing a string **you** have to take care about proper escaping! - Edit: oops, thought it's jQuery. no idea if you can pass an object in YUI but it would make sense if you could...

Answer (score 0):

Host the server-side script (hostname.com/start) via SSL (HTTPS).

Put it (your UI page) behind a password-protected login page.

You'll probably need to host your UI from the same domain and port.

Comment: Even this way, authenticated yours can submit arbitrary code for server side execution. That's a general no-no.

Comment: I guess it depends on what runs the mapper/reducer functions (they can be sandboxed environments) - but I agree, it's asking for trouble :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pick a language that can express exactly what you want to allow the users to do and no more, and then have the server accept only input written in that language.  This can be an existing language, a subset of an existing language or a language entirely of your own design.

Without more information it's a little hard for us to suggest a suitable language.

Comment: I would not be suprised if the language was to be selected is JavaScript.

Comment: It must be a language executed on the server side - so a subset of JavaScript might qualify, e.g. when the server runs `node.js`.